# Можно ли как-то получить параметры печати страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо печатать страницу и в конце каждой проставлять подпись.

Проблема в том, что по мере увеличения контента страницы увеличивается и количество страниц на печать, а подпись нужна на каждой странице.

Представляю реализацию как-то так: через js получаю параметры страницы, редактирую их, и потом вывожу печатать.

Существует ли такой функционал вообще?

Если да, и если это сложно реализуется, то существуют ли какие нибудь библиотеки, готовые решения?

Или мне придется как-то по-другому реализовывать подобный функционал? (например качать файл для печати, потом скармливать его какой-то функции, которая будет проставлять подпись в конце каждой страницы)

Comment: Решения на js может не существовать. По крайней мере два года назад ничего похожего не было. Выход - генерировать документ на печать на сервере и там уже проставлять что и куда вам надо)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну да, я так и подумал. а жаль...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока, только так, вроде бы. Но есть надежда, что скоро все измениться - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#intro

```css
.signature {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  color:red
}
@media print {
  .signature {
    display: block;
  }
  body {
    margin: 2cm; 
  } 
  @page{
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut saepe maiores earum optio laboriosam autem voluptates voluptas fuga dolorem iusto odio non, illo accusamus eos dicta consectetur eveniet maxime error reprehenderit. Magni mollitia nisi velit labore quasi dolorem a repellat aut assumenda, minima fuga eveniet neque temporibus. Et quam recusandae numquam dolores molestias quae vitae voluptatum atque earum omnis aperiam nesciunt, eligendi eveniet consequatur fuga perferendis perspiciatis dolorem a alias possimus maxime reiciendis molestiae sit nihil! Voluptatem ducimus ab voluptate in pariatur quisquam corporis inventore itaque asperiores, laborum, magnam praesentium vero soluta necessitatibus mollitia quasi impedit veritatis numquam recusandae repudiandae non ullam odio. Repellat consequuntur assumenda qui ducimus? In, esse ipsa, laboriosam fugit eos consectetur, animi fugiat itaque corrupti asperiores deserunt assumenda quia dolorum sapiente quam laudantium voluptatum ab iusto inventore quaerat rem nulla ducimus vero nihil? Amet dicta omnis, adipisci exercitationem ipsum aliquid ducimus, voluptatem et aperiam soluta, illum eveniet vitae. Eveniet eligendi ab delectus, nesciunt pariatur voluptate, incidunt est eum cupiditate modi perspiciatis reiciendis dolorum? Corporis modi, eos earum ut eaque quaerat placeat nisi aspernatur explicabo quam omnis aperiam dolore praesentium nostrum facere ab nobis numquam libero voluptatibus fuga consequuntur odit debitis reprehenderit. Amet accusamus, nesciunt, unde atque perferendis corrupti laborum laudantium deleniti modi at aperiam. Nobis libero fugit quia mollitia id excepturi cumque voluptatem cum distinctio repudiandae! Labore repudiandae debitis illum saepe quaerat deleniti dolorum quis totam vitae nihil impedit necessitatibus suscipit expedita velit ipsum, officiis veniam ea laborum, ex praesentium eaque soluta eligendi. Iste quaerat fugiat consectetur perferendis animi accusamus incidunt natus. Laboriosam cum deserunt, ullam veniam laudantium ab alias iste. Quas, laborum accusantium quis ad expedita facilis debitis neque dolores fugiat similique illo aliquam quisquam magni amet, repellat hic possimus obcaecati sint tempore quos aperiam cupiditate? Aliquam officia tenetur laborum ipsa consequuntur dolores minus modi asperiores, dolorem, omnis velit qui architecto sint iusto assumenda non sequi incidunt. Delectus magni veritatis amet ea exercitationem hic deserunt laborum soluta asperiores perferendis. Minima tempora repudiandae ipsa ut dolor! Sapiente vel, consequuntur id quia hic quos dolorum similique laudantium cupiditate cumque voluptatum sequi ipsam perspiciatis nihil adipisci saepe nulla accusantium. Corporis, aliquam in. Ducimus, cum sint quae amet hic eos soluta molestiae minima facere maiores? Nulla nobis, est sapiente saepe aliquam, atque, quaerat quo unde porro nisi fuga totam quae error omnis laborum? Atque fugiat, qui repellendus vel magnam enim libero similique accusantium, ratione earum at tempore! Voluptatem praesentium sunt commodi eveniet in repellendus minima odio consequuntur, tempora ex, suscipit facilis porro odit perferendis, nostrum distinctio hic? Minus labore illum, cum beatae et velit iste corrupti ratione maiores atque placeat expedita consequatur maxime quam, eius ipsum, distinctio dolor necessitatibus? Consequatur excepturi necessitatibus cupiditate pariatur recusandae ut nobis culpa magnam maxime iusto modi quis, expedita eaque nam amet dignissimos. Cum voluptatem soluta magni amet rerum porro eius alias saepe necessitatibus, quisquam aliquid esse commodi, doloremque sequi maiores repellat assumenda itaque! Quisquam illum ad odit laboriosam consequatur quidem dignissimos eveniet animi delectus pariatur tempora praesentium veritatis hic voluptates voluptatum fuga quia, autem, placeat dolorum ullam, earum non modi? Mollitia, soluta excepturi iusto dolorum quibusdam tempora labore, adipisci, atque esse magnam inventore culpa qui. Omnis, corrupti corporis iste sapiente error inventore vel enim beatae molestias totam nisi dolor esse veritatis perspiciatis a ad neque natus! Quo tenetur accusantium unde in laboriosam ipsam eveniet iste, aut sapiente esse porro amet! Saepe repellat ex dolorum, enim iste veritatis veniam qui rem molestiae officia hic ratione fugit voluptatem sit esse tempora molestias natus delectus quod. Reprehenderit, doloremque placeat. Provident nam ipsam, iure enim sunt labore placeat. Saepe, quaerat qui, vero similique consectetur perspiciatis iusto perferendis porro natus quam molestias deserunt eligendi exercitationem, blanditiis facere tenetur aperiam architecto! Placeat autem, rem illum ab molestiae accusantium inventore tenetur rerum consequatur possimus laboriosam obcaecati laudantium labore nemo dolorum cumque eveniet, temporibus ea corporis dolore facilis explicabo voluptatem. Est harum voluptates hic qui iure quod illo quam enim veniam tempore nulla, labore fugiat ea! Necessitatibus nihil possimus neque fuga in beatae dolores architecto aliquid! Quis saepe nobis ratione maiores odio, laborum culpa assumenda, magni quisquam consectetur, voluptatibus quasi consequatur aliquid. Sunt officia delectus veritatis libero voluptatibus labore doloribus magnam molestias commodi id tempore nisi, ipsum obcaecati ab. Ex, aliquid minus. Temporibus assumenda accusantium sequi ducimus officiis rerum iste id, quasi, impedit quaerat velit ipsa? Est vitae voluptate maxime inventore consectetur, quas amet at? Architecto excepturi sed nobis veritatis minus voluptates a veniam ipsam accusantium praesentium. Quasi incidunt laboriosam eaque tempora provident hic corporis accusantium quam quibusdam nesciunt? Fuga eum explicabo id harum doloribus at vitae corrupti minus, maiores, illum, recusandae reiciendis atque rem praesentium totam ab officia quidem ad quam fugit quia eligendi! Saepe rem ducimus consectetur, velit voluptatum tempora eum! Mollitia, officiis? Non, reiciendis dolore ab soluta saepe reprehenderit, totam itaque tempore, nobis delectus amet aut. Reprehenderit, in vitae vel temporibus quas, voluptatem quam velit omnis explicabo, similique atque sequi pariatur. Totam voluptate explicabo amet dicta voluptates ad est vel quisquam esse! Eius totam aut odit neque ratione at, maxime excepturi, eaque non exercitationem sapiente quia, eveniet et temporibus expedita eligendi incidunt quae nostrum eum. Sunt laborum magni eveniet nisi dicta omnis aperiam tempora nesciunt, necessitatibus consectetur officiis quasi reiciendis odio fugiat! Atque, excepturi similique quis blanditiis fuga maiores non sequi inventore facere repellendus quibusdam expedita perferendis natus, harum ducimus. Et ipsa optio doloribus quae perspiciatis, iure voluptate placeat fugit quisquam at, similique officiis, nisi vel repellat suscipit? Aperiam porro praesentium quae ratione! Dignissimos dolore doloremque eius repellat iusto possimus quis quisquam minus at atque, facilis reiciendis! Cum modi magnam debitis cupiditate repudiandae? Ipsum aliquam consequatur minus voluptas debitis consequuntur fugiat illo culpa ea in, et commodi laudantium odit doloribus officiis pariatur voluptatum eius iste obcaecati saepe. Commodi tempore laborum deserunt. Odit dolores nostrum, modi magni porro suscipit quis accusantium aperiam quaerat numquam blanditiis ut rem laudantium non doloremque, doloribus voluptatibus perferendis animi tenetur, obcaecati repudiandae soluta! Fuga architecto eius ipsum officiis esse obcaecati repellendus officia quod in excepturi quo, saepe dolore temporibus autem corporis ullam fugit numquam laborum consequuntur odit eligendi tempore quis error maiores? Labore voluptas et ab quo officia temporibus, in aliquam omnis dicta porro doloremque accusantium perspiciatis ullam repudiandae impedit quam deserunt. Tenetur dolorum maxime pariatur, culpa aliquam ipsum facere. Ullam repellat minus quisquam praesentium itaque ex dignissimos nam laboriosam, mollitia, iure fuga blanditiis eaque maxime aliquam rerum minima id officia veniam dolore. Aut, a officia! Ut delectus quasi labore dolorem animi quidem, eos quod quas ullam aspernatur mollitia dicta perspiciatis repellendus cupiditate molestias voluptatem veniam rem saepe incidunt assumenda? Culpa eos deleniti maiores dolor, dolores ex aspernatur! Laboriosam eaque sint voluptatem facere et atque quas, culpa maiores obcaecati temporibus similique ipsum in magni sequi officia dignissimos illo porro incidunt? Ratione eum, voluptates recusandae mollitia omnis optio esse saepe et officiis asperiores neque, eligendi voluptatibus sint exercitationem commodi! Hic, unde nulla! Similique beatae cum alias molestiae corrupti aspernatur. Ad ea eum, laboriosam nulla excepturi magnam animi quas velit porro placeat sit nostrum sed voluptates aperiam dolorum, nihil rem corporis illo enim fugiat optio rerum culpa vel. Laudantium, officia. Doloribus, vero mollitia cupiditate commodi dolorem, laborum reiciendis earum iure totam veniam odio consectetur corporis harum deleniti dicta ea corrupti? Iusto saepe unde ipsam esse deserunt quam molestias illo pariatur repellat fugit hic velit eos ratione perferendis sapiente obcaecati quos, maiores asperiores voluptates. Pariatur quod tenetur facilis nemo nulla quisquam facere ab dolorem nesciunt enim nostrum assumenda blanditiis mollitia modi voluptatem vitae cupiditate eveniet minima, tempora sunt, architecto illum esse possimus tempore! Explicabo dolore magni placeat recusandae porro? Doloremque ipsa hic id possimus quos delectus molestiae ut corporis nobis tempore quod omnis consequatur in, vel ea sequi reiciendis totam voluptates est, dolore obcaecati nemo repudiandae officiis odio. Quod velit laboriosam aut doloremque enim id iusto deleniti excepturi illo temporibus tempora quo, nihil mollitia repellat ratione commodi, officiis numquam fuga voluptatem vitae molestias repudiandae corporis explicabo! Consequatur voluptatum quasi corporis molestias laborum repudiandae obcaecati culpa! Quasi accusantium cupiditate sint labore voluptas inventore amet! Aperiam dignissimos impedit tempora ratione quas id aliquam, fuga porro amet expedita voluptas quaerat magnam ab beatae est sequi? Consectetur impedit dicta vel blanditiis molestiae repellendus culpa illo, pariatur nulla totam officia explicabo in tempore? Harum, aliquid libero, maiores non atque ipsa qui excepturi sunt ex id accusantium similique vel earum repudiandae distinctio dignissimos culpa commodi error velit illo quaerat nulla quos debitis eos? Minima voluptate maiores reiciendis, sit repudiandae assumenda quod dolor, quidem officiis recusandae aliquam tenetur nobis. Error consequuntur placeat eveniet! Mollitia architecto soluta odio voluptas magnam veniam, dolor reprehenderit ratione vel illo at non officiis fuga saepe necessitatibus voluptate ullam quas officia accusantium esse. Molestias commodi nulla ipsa, eveniet nisi laborum consectetur nostrum repudiandae libero dignissimos at accusamus porro? Laudantium modi consequatur eligendi nemo eaque ducimus ipsum deleniti, nihil maxime architecto nisi quae, voluptatibus dignissimos itaque labore aliquid sed placeat! Distinctio hic impedit minima doloribus illum delectus voluptas expedita eveniet consequuntur veritatis. Unde corrupti saepe eum sed temporibus reiciendis blanditiis maxime, quasi voluptate eius modi sequi pariatur animi laudantium accusamus magni inventore nemo esse tempora fugit, doloremque placeat itaque porro illum. Tenetur quam quia voluptate quae, hic at quidem accusantium dolorum ipsam! Aliquid temporibus eum nostrum nam ad, animi id eaque aspernatur numquam veniam magnam saepe, velit laborum deserunt vel? Dicta, autem, sit qui praesentium excepturi itaque reiciendis quaerat cupiditate voluptatum nemo officia aut delectus aspernatur inventore laudantium eaque deleniti sunt iure hic et cumque nesciunt? Quasi perspiciatis temporibus, id similique assumenda veniam, adipisci natus illum magni nesciunt eius porro earum consequatur autem reiciendis dolorem ad cumque incidunt minus deserunt voluptas, repellendus necessitatibus. Alias ipsa dolore sapiente veritatis ipsam animi quas vel provident quaerat, labore natus dolorum possimus quasi ducimus neque. Adipisci, cum repellendus. Quasi odio, quae, veritatis numquam nisi doloribus sint voluptates tempora repellat corrupti eligendi quis dolores. Eum eligendi cumque sint asperiores porro laudantium perspiciatis, officiis doloribus voluptate omnis quod sequi nulla magni, reiciendis repudiandae consectetur placeat natus modi! Id pariatur libero dolores sapiente repudiandae veritatis unde dolore eum odio, enim aliquam optio! Nisi quisquam mollitia beatae. Voluptatum dolore in perspiciatis, tempore repudiandae soluta ducimus accusamus quisquam sapiente corrupti voluptatem tenetur molestias? Minus iure ad laudantium ipsum, eius nisi eveniet non odit recusandae molestiae vitae, accusamus fugit perspiciatis? Corporis libero dignissimos exercitationem voluptatem harum sed at blanditiis quas ea magni ullam enim quam, inventore doloribus possimus quasi minus odit quisquam! Delectus eligendi, veritatis similique deserunt beatae recusandae dolor ea magni possimus, ducimus repellendus minima accusamus aperiam est doloribus labore fugit dolore molestias suscipit! Ipsam vel tempore fugiat! Nemo laborum fugit, sit unde fugiat nobis reiciendis quaerat, ea porro at facilis, vitae totam perferendis corporis! Molestiae dignissimos facilis quas, culpa temporibus maiores error mollitia voluptates tenetur saepe tempora laboriosam exercitationem doloremque. Tempora dicta amet nam rerum eveniet non quia officia. Ex, minima eaque ipsum eum aspernatur deleniti quibusdam dolores, natus quisquam explicabo cum doloremque cumque. Voluptate placeat, praesentium ex rem quis delectus atque nam ab omnis ea, suscipit saepe veritatis recusandae, quam fugit sint quae incidunt illo quibusdam in. Harum totam nulla eius delectus! Laborum, deleniti, deserunt tempore quod asperiores ut eum, consequatur nemo odit voluptas id cum incidunt! Cumque sed magni corrupti nostrum perspiciatis magnam assumenda, ipsam aperiam ratione vel maxime tempore earum atque a ea. Sint mollitia enim et atque, dolorum nesciunt, hic saepe asperiores a commodi provident magnam delectus magni id tenetur adipisci vitae expedita nam eaque tempore exercitationem odit amet? Iste sequi quisquam id, officiis, cupiditate voluptas reprehenderit illum totam in atque quasi cum eligendi magni nostrum hic quam placeat consequuntur voluptatem provident quidem facere? Dolorem beatae, error alias odio quisquam, soluta animi facilis tempore aliquam unde ducimus quidem omnis est. Quo blanditiis, fuga reprehenderit suscipit quia consectetur culpa atque. Dolores deserunt deleniti perspiciatis ex voluptate debitis modi laborum, itaque ullam molestias. Voluptate quasi vitae earum! Ad cumque a suscipit nesciunt quod corrupti illum debitis, quia minima culpa qui nemo eius recusandae fugit quo ipsa iste optio. Voluptate iste, veritatis rem ipsum modi quidem ipsam provident minus dolores, commodi vitae quae totam delectus aliquid recusandae illo.
      <div class="signature">signature</div>
    </div>
```

Чтобы воспроизвести - необходимо развернуть код на всю cтраницу и нажать Ctrl+p